# How to reference the child scope from the parent controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

The following code simply displays a form and saves the input with a `editDownload` method:

**JS:**

```
$scope.editDownload = function(downloadId) {
  var Download = Parse.Object.extend('Download')
  var download = new Download()
  var data = {
    'title': $scope.download.title,
    'link': $scope.download.link
  }
  download.save(data, {
    success: function(result) {
      console.log('Success:', result.toJSON())
    },
    error: function(result, error) {
      alert('Error:', error.message)
    }
  })
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="text-center no-bullet">
  <li ng-repeat="download in downloads">
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="download.title">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="download.link">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editDownload('{{download.objectId}}')">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

There's a problem, though, `$scope.download.title` and `$scope.download` become `undefined` because their values are being set inside an `ng-repeat` hence in a different scope.

How can reference this 'child' scope from the parent controller?

*Note:* I can't do `$parent.download.title` and `$parent.download.link` in the template because then the `ng-model` won't display anything (it won't be referencing the children in the ng-repeat anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the parameter to `editDownload()` through an expression. You can just pass `editDownload(download.objectId)`.

The resultant button tag would look like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editDownload(download.objectId)">Submit</button>
```

Also, `$scope.download` does not refer to the `download` in ng-repeat.

If you want to do something with the `download` object that you're passing through `editDownload()`, you can just pass the object itself as the parameter.

```
editDownload(download)
```

Instead of passing `download.objectId` as the param.

Finally, it should look like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editDownload(download)">Submit</button>
```